# Dynamically load content in Bootstrap nav-tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="tabpanes" style="display: none;">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Klantgegevens</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Documenten</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#references" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">...</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">

  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">...</div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
function klantdetails(id = null) {

    if(id){

        $("#tabpanes").show();
        $("#profile").load("php/getklantinfo.php", "id=id");


    }


}
```

When the function is called, nothing seems te happen. However, if I click another nav link, and then return to the first one, the content is loaded in the #profile tab pane. What's the reason it's not visible immediately?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by removing the fade class from the first tabpanel.